# Subquery join not working as expected when trying to join an array

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to craft a query for a user that will retrieve other users with whom this user has not yet interacted.

Suppose the following:

```
create schema if not exists bv;

create table if not exists bv.user (
  id serial primary key,
  user_name varchar(15) not null,
  is_male boolean not null
);

create table if not exists bv.chat (
  id serial primary key
);

create table if not exists bv.chat_message (
  id serial primary key,
  chat_id bigint references bv.chat (id),
  user_id bigint references bv.user (id),
  message_text varchar(255) not null
);

create table if not exists bv.junction_user_chat (
  chat_id bigint references bv.chat (id),
  user_id bigint references bv.user (id)
);

create table if not exists bv.user_coordinates (
  id serial primary key,
  user_id bigint references bv.user (id)
);

create table if not exists bv.user_like (
  id serial primary key,
  source_user_id bigint references bv.user (id),
  target_user_id bigint references bv.user (id)
);
```

```
insert into bv.user values
  (100, 'Mike', true),
  (101, 'John', true),
  (102, 'Jane', false),
  (103, 'George', true),
  (104, 'Lance', true);
insert into bv.chat values
  (10);
insert into bv.junction_user_chat values
  (10, 101),
  (10, 102);
insert into bv.chat_message values
  (500, 10, 101, 'hello'),
  (501, 10, 102, 'how are you?');
insert into bv.user_coordinates values
  (777, 100),
  (778, 101),
  (779, 102),
  (780, 103),
  (781, 104);
insert into bv.user_like values
  (1, 101, 102),
  (2, 102, 101),
  (3, 100, 102),
  (4, 103, 102),
  (5, 102, 104);
```

Let's assume I am **user with ID 102 (Jane)**. I would expect my query to return,

```
┌──────┬────────────────────┬──────────┐
│ id   │ user_name          │ is_male  │
├──────┼────────────────────┼──────────┤
│ 100  │ Mike               │ true     │
│ 103  │ George             │ true     │
└──────┴────────────────────┴──────────┘
```

Some remarks:

- Users 102 and 101 already have a chat (and chat messages) between them, which why user 101 is not returned in the query,
- User 102 does not exist as the `source_user_id` in `bv."user_like"` — if they did exist in that table, then user 103 would not be returned in the query
- Users 100 and 103 are returned because,

  - they've both "liked" user 102,
  - user 102 not exist as `bv."user_like"."souce_user_id"`,
  - a chat doesn't exist for neither users `102 - 100` nor `102 - 103`
- User 104 is not returned because user 102 already "liked" them (even though user 104 hasn't liked user 102 back at the moment)

Again, the idea here is to return all users that the current user(with id 102) hasn't interacted with. By "interaction" I mean a record in `bv."user_like"`, `bv."chat"` or `bv."chat_message"`.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u.id)
    u.*
FROM bv.user_coordinates uc
JOIN bv.user u
    ON u.id = uc.user_id
JOIN (
    SELECT
      user_id,
      chat_id
    FROM bv.junction_user_chat
) chat_ids
  ON chat_ids.user_id = 102
LEFT JOIN bv.user_like ul
    ON u.id = ul.target_user_id
    AND ul.source_user_id = 102
LEFT JOIN bv.chat_message cm 
    ON cm.chat_id = any(chat_ids)
    AND (cm.user_id = u.id OR cm.user_id = 102)
WHERE u.id != 102
AND uc.user_id = u.id
AND u.is_male = true
AND ul.id is null
AND cm.id is null
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.id ASC
```

The problem is that I am unsure of how to make use of `junction_user_chat` here. Ideally, I'd like to form an array `chat_ids` (as I've tried to do), and then check to see if user ID `102` is present; if it is, then I'd like to omit it from the result.

How can I get this to work, is my approach even in the correct direction? Postgres' array methods and data types are new to me in general, I'm much more used to junction tables, so I'd much more prefer that over the current attempt with the nested join and `ANY` comparison.

I will finally mention that this is a severely slimmed-down version of the actual query, which is why you are seeing a `select...from bv.user_coordinates`. This part can change, but I kept it in here just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following ?

```js
with chats_of_user as (
  select distinct chat_id
  from bv.user userA
  join bv.junction_user_chat chatA
  on userA.id = chatA.user_id
  where userA.id= 102
),
users_not_involed_in_chat as (
  select id
  from bv.user
  where bv.user.id NOT IN (
    select distinct userChatA.user_id
    from chats_of_user
    join bv.junction_user_chat userChatA
    on userChatA.chat_id = chats_of_user.chat_id
  )
),
not_liked_users as (
  select id
  from bv.user
  where id NOT IN (
    select distinct userLike.target_user_id
    from bv.user userA
    join bv.user_like userLike
    on userA.id = userLike.source_user_id
    where userA.id = 102

  ) 
)
select users_not_involed_in_chat.id
from users_not_involed_in_chat 
join not_liked_users
on users_not_involed_in_chat.id = not_liked_users.id
;
```

This is working in the above scenario. You can check for other cases extensively. Please also check the perf once using `explain analyze`

Answer (score 0):

You can summarize this problem as:

- getting the id of your chosen user
- getting user_fans ids (people he is being liked from)
- getting user_talkers ids (people he has talked to)
- getting fans he has not talked to (user_fans except user_talkers)
- retrieve user data for the remaining fans

```
WITH chosen_user AS (
    SELECT id AS user_id
    FROM bv.user
    WHERE user_name = 'Jane'
), user_fans AS (
    SELECT source_user_id AS user_id
    FROM       bv.user_like 
    INNER JOIN chosen_user
            ON user_like.target_user_id = chosen_user.user_id
), user_talkers AS (
    SELECT user_chatters.user_id
    FROM       bv.junction_user_chat user_chats
    INNER JOIN chosen_user
            ON user_chats.user_id = chosen_user.user_id
    INNER JOIN bv.junction_user_chat user_chatters
            ON user_chatters.chat_id = user_chats.chat_id
    WHERE NOT user_chatters.user_id = chosen_user.user_id 
), fans_to_interact_with AS (
    SELECT * FROM user_fans
    EXCEPT ALL
    SELECT * FROM user_talkers
)
SELECT bv.user.*
FROM       fans_to_interact_with
INNER JOIN bv.user
        ON fans_to_interact_with.user_id = bv.user.id
```

**Output**:

| id | user_name | is_male |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Mike | true |
| 103 | George | true |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6fuuoZiJ6vWzykvu9QtrCc/0).

---

If you are filtering already on the chosen user id you need, you can simplify this solution into:

```
WITH user_fans AS (
    SELECT source_user_id AS user_id
    FROM bv.user_like 
    WHERE target_user_id = 102
), user_talkers AS (
    SELECT user_chatters.user_id
    FROM       bv.junction_user_chat user_chats
    INNER JOIN bv.junction_user_chat user_chatters
            ON user_chatters.chat_id = user_chats.chat_id
    WHERE user_chats.user_id = 102
      AND NOT user_chatters.user_id = 102
      
), fans_to_interact_with AS (
    SELECT * FROM user_fans
    EXCEPT ALL
    SELECT * FROM user_talkers
)
SELECT bv.user.*
FROM       fans_to_interact_with
INNER JOIN bv.user
        ON fans_to_interact_with.user_id = bv.user.id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6fuuoZiJ6vWzykvu9QtrCc/1).